# How can I wrap a closure in a closure?

Tags: c++, closures

This is my particular use case, but I'm sure there are others:

I pass a callback closure to a function that may run in a different thread. The code in the closure may throw an exception. I don't want that exception to kill my program. I'm happy to catch it and report it. (Yes, I know that doing this can result in resource leaks; I'm ignoring this issue for now.)

There are hundreds of these closures in my code, so I don't want to edit every single one of them to add try…catch clauses to them. I'd prefer to have a short wrapper around the closures instead.

My sample code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
     
int   
main()
{
    string str("Hello, world");

    // Program will die because of exception thrown in handler.
    context->invoke(
        [str](bool success) {
            cout << str << ": " << success << endl;
            throw exception();
        }
    );

    myThread.join();

    // I want my program to not die
    context->invoke(
        []{exceptionCatcher(
            [str](bool success) {
                cout << str << ": " << success << endl;
                throw exception();
            }
        );}
    );

    myThread2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

and then my `exceptionCatcher` template looks something like this:

```
template<typename Func>
void exceptionCatcher(Func func)
{
    try {
        func();
    }
    catch (const exception& e) {
        cout << "Caught exception\n";
    }
}
```

except that the compiler doesn't like this.

```
c++ -std=c++17 -o tester tester.cpp
tester.cpp:40:14: error: variable 'str' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no
      capture-default specified
            [str]{
             ^
tester.cpp:23:12: note: 'str' declared here
    string str("Hello, world");
           ^
tester.cpp:39:9: note: lambda expression begins here
        []{exceptionCatcher(
```

What's the magic incantation to write `exceptionCatcher`?

Complication: There are many such "invoke" functions. The captured values and the arguments to the closure are varied. Is it possible to write a wrapper that handles all these cases?

Comment: You should not be creating thrown exception dynamically.  Throw them by value instead: `throw exception();`

Comment: Actually, that was almost going to be the subject of another question: which form is preferred? I guess I have my answer; thanks. I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Note: I've updated the code per @Jason's suggestion. Error message is now different.

Comment: You didn't capture `str` in the outer lambda, so it is not available in the inner lambda.

Comment: I've updated my question to better show my use case. My closure could capture any variables _and_ it accepts varying arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You lambda won't be a pointer. It is always passed by value.

```
template <typename Func>
void exceptionCatcher(Func func)
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks; that almost worked. The problem is that the inner closure captures a value (`[str]`). That only works if the outer closure captures the same variable. Sadly, I suspect I won't have a choice there.

Comment: You don't really need to use a lambda to call `exceptionHandler()`, as `std::thread` accepts any callable, including functions, eg: `auto func = [str]{ ... }; myThread2(exceptionCatcher<decltype(func)>, func);` [demo](https://ideone.com/EIhTeq). Alternatively: `void exceptionCatcher(std::function<void()> func) {  ... func(); ... } thread myThread2(exceptionCatcher, [str]{ ... });` [demo](https://ideone.com/zN054X)

Comment: OK, that compiled and ran on my system. It depends on the constructor of std::thread that takes the function pointer and args separately. My *actual* use case is a wrapper around std::thread, and I'm not sure the wrapper can take those arguments. Stand by while I test it.

Comment: I guess I'm guilty of oversimplifying. I'm going to edit my question to more accurately reflect my use case.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't capture `str` in the outer lambda, so it is not available in the inner lambda.

If `invoke()` allows you to pass the callable object and its parameters separately (like `std::thread`'s constructor allows), then you can do something like this:

```cpp
template<typename Func>
void exceptionCatcher(Func func)
{
    try {
        func(success);
    }
    catch (const exception& e) {
        cout << "Caught exception\n";
    }
}

auto func = [str](bool success) {
    cout << str << ": " << success << endl;
    throw exception();
};

context->invoke(
    exceptionCatcher<decltype(func)>,
    func
);
```

Alternatively:

```
void exceptionCatcher(std::function<void(bool)> func)
{
    try {
        func(success);
    }
    catch (const exception& e) {
        cout << "Caught exception\n";
    }
}

context->invoke(
    exceptionCatcher,
    [str](bool success){
        cout << str << ": " << success << endl;
        throw exception();
    }
);
```

Otherwise, if that is not an option, you will just have to add an additional capture to your outer lambda:

```
context->invoke(
    [str]{ // <-- add this
        exceptionCatcher(
            [str](bool success) {
                cout << str << ": " << success << endl;
                throw exception();
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: OK, thanks, I was thinking this was where I was headed. I toyed with using `std::function()`, but I understand there's significant overhead for using that.